# How should a replacement outlet be wired?

Tags: wiring

I have a non-GFI 15A kitchen electrical outlet that stopped working and I went to replace it, ground white and black where it should be, but dead.

I tested black wire and it reads 120. Is it possible it is daisy chained and needs to have both white and black attached on hot side separately?

I could have sworn, when I took old one out, each wire was connected to their respective side.

Please advise, thank you.

Comment: How did you test the black to get 120V?, what wires did you use?

Comment: Are you saying that the new, replacement outlet is also dead? No, the wires should not both go to one side. Please revise to clarify your steps and the problem.

Comment: You had it right originally. **Did you  turn off the power before changing the outlet?**

Comment: did you test between black wire and white wire?

Answer (score 1):

Since you measured 120v you probably have an open neutral. I find open wiring most often when back stabs are used. A back stab is the push in type of connection. I don’t like back stabs and think they should be illegal but have made many house payments fixing them. The problem is usually on the last working outlet or first non working outlet. Bathrooms and kitchens have this problem quite often other than that space heaters will usually cause the problem. It could be a broken wire or a wire that came out of the nut but that is rare compared to bad back stabs. Also don’t assume a non contact voltage tester is correct and you have 120v it could be a phantom voltage on a circuit that was turned off at the breaker. Note as others have said you had the wires correct with black wire on the brass colored screw , white wire on the silver screw and bare copper or green insulation going to the green screw. If you put white and black on the same side it would have tripped the breaker if the breaker was tripped you need to turn it fully off and then on to reset it.